# ARCore Android in Unity - App not starting

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Following this official tutorial  with a clean project https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android for building and running an ARCore application in Android, the sample scene HelloAR is not starting.

Instant preview in the game view is not working also, white screen is shown instead of the camera render.

My version of Unity is 2019.1.10f1, ARCore SDK version is 1.10.0. Android device is an Xiaomi Mi Mix 2S with Android 9

Looking in the log with adb there is an error:

```
07-19 02:27:19.249 10720 10740 D Unity   : Unable to lookup library path for 'arcore_instant_preview_unity_plugin', native render plugin support disabled.
07-19 02:27:19.250 10720 10740 E Unity   : Unable to find arcore_instant_preview_unity_plugin
```

Comment: Did you check the option "AR Core Supported" in Player settings?

Comment: Yes, it is checked, but the plugin is no loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem with the setup of:

- Unity 2019.2.6f
- ARCore SDK 1.12
- Samsung S10e

and I made it work by disabling Instant preview in Project Setting -> Instant preview enabled -> unable the box

[Unable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b8Xj.png)

It does not solve the problem of previewing in the Editor but solves the white screen